# Debugging/finding scripts loaded by RequireJS

Tags: javascript, debugging, requirejs

I have just started using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to load the scripts for my page, but have hit a roadblock when trying to debug a problem using chrome.

Let's say that I have my main script that relies on two dependencies: `dep1` and `dep2`

```
require(["dep1", "dep2"], function(dep1, dep2) {
    //do something
});
```

Whilst running unit tests I notice that something in `dep1.js` isn't working correctly, so I open up chrome dev tools to insert a breakpoint, except...

[image: missing dependencies]

...`dep1.js` doesn't exist!

How do I locate the source file to insert my breakpoint?!

I am sure that the files *are* being loaded as the scripts are being run correctly. I just can't see them in the list of sources

Comment: @downvoter - any comment/reason for downvoting?

Comment: Another way to verify / access the loaded sources is via the Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools. You can right-click on the source to view it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally realised the problem was that I was using `r.js` instead of `require.js`.  As soon as I switched I could see the files without a problem.

As an aside, a temporary work-around was to insert the line below at the end of the inserted files.  This *just about* gets chrome to pick up on the files.

```
//@ sourceURL=GameWorldAction.js
```

Comment: Quite interesting this was my suggestion one month before you posted this (see below), but not a single upvote..

Comment: @RobbertvandenBogerd I don't see any answer besides the one from jeremyawesome. If you mean your comment on that answer then yes, that's true - you should have posted it as a separate answer!

Comment: @RobbertvandenBogerd +1 upboats from the future!

Answer (score 1):

You never close your array in your example above.

```
require(["dep1", "dep2", function(dep1, dep2) {
    //do something
});
```

Should be:

```
require(["dep1", "dep2"], function(dep1, dep2) {
    //do something
});
```

**Edit in Response to Update to Question:**

I am assuming `r.js` is the RequireJs file. It looks like RequireJS is not loading the files correctly, if it had then the files would've shown up in your inspector.

Are you using the `data-main` attribute on your `script` tag to specify a main JS file? If so, are the `dep1` and `dep2` files in the same directory as the main JS file? You might have to specify a different `baseUrl` if you are trying to load files from a different path or domain. You can change the baseUrl by setting it in the require.config.

```
<script>
  require.config({
    //path can also be a domain like "//image.mydomain.tld/jscript"
    baseUrl: "/another/path" 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The example was typed directly into SO - the array is closed in the real code.  I've updated the question

Comment: Yes, I am using the `data-main` attribute and the files are definitely loading correctly (I can see that because my tests are running).  I am actually specifying a separate `baseUrl` as well as some `path` mappings but I don't think that's the problem

Comment: I hadn't, but (at first glance) that's about scripts disappearing rather than never appearing in the first place. I'll read through though

Comment: @jeremysawesome your assumption is wrong, r.js is the requireJS optimizer

Comment: @RobbertvandenBogerd really it is? Are you sure it's not another random JavaScript file named "r.js"? You can't be sure, you must be assuming that the `r.js` file is the optimizer. The point is: if `r.js` was not the RequireJS file then the OP was not including a necessary file. However, in the future, rather than assuming, I will simply ask "are you including the require.js file? Because the screenshot doesn't show it."